# sql-maven-plugin escaping single quotes in sqlCommand

Tags: sql, xml, maven-2, sql-maven-plugin

I have maven based project and I try to use sql-maven-plugin in order to setup/tear-down DB for system tests.
I put in sqlCommand element:

`CALL SOME_STORED_PROC('SYSTEST')`

however, maven build fails on this SQL with the followig exception:

`org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: 
ERROR:  Function 'SOME_STORED_PROC(UNKNOWN)' does not exist
 Unable to identify a function that satisfies the given argument types
 You may need to add explicit typecasts`

I suspect that the argument of the stored procedure needs to be escaped in some special way. I failed to find any docs/ examples.

Any thoughts?

Aviad

Comment: Perhaps you should post the relevant pom snippet.  Possibly maven is unable to find the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument to stored procedure needs to be double guoted. that actually helped the situation